# show author avatar

Tags: avatar

I have modified the loop.php file to add some comment stuff in. I wanted to show a comment off a link which is working just fine. Now I went to make that comment show more detail by putting the author avatar. So my code looks like this. It does display the default avatar but is should display my image which it is not.

```
 $comments = get_comments( array(
    'post_id' => $post->ID,
    'number'  => '1' 
 ) );
foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
    echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID'), 32 );
    echo $comment->comment_author . ' says: ';
    echo '<hr />';
    echo $comment->comment_content;
}
```

Comment: **About the question** What exact part should display your default image and how did you add a default image? **Formatting & the WYSIWG editor**: Jamie, please take care about formatting. You want an answer, so please take your time to format your question as well as possible. Thanks.

Comment: I will do my best to improve my formatting and details in my questions from now on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The get_the_author_meta function gets the Post's author ID, not the comment-author's information.

The get_avatar() function is perfectly capable of accepting the comment object whole and working it out from that all by itself. So just call it like so:

`echo get_avatar( $comment, 32 );`

Comment: Not, that the question is really clear, but how does this answer _"(...)It does display the default avatar but is should display my image which it is not."_ ?

Comment: it's interesting how sometimes reading the codex and send you off in the wrong direction. This worked. Thank you

Comment: kaiser: Sometimes you have to read between the lines. ;)